# replace placeholders properties in spring/tomcat docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a Dockerfile such as:

```
FROM tomcat:8.5

COPY webapp.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
COPY conf /usr/local/tomcat/conf/

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

`conf` contains many types of files (.json, .xml, .properties) with some placeholders in them with the following format: `${some.place.holder}`

I want to build the image with the placeholders, and give to my users the possibility to replace them.

Ideally, when running the image, they should be able to give a new file as a parameter such as:

```
some.place.holder=hello
```

What would be the correct way to achive that?

Comment: Add an example file

Comment: There is some XML, some spring property files, some json files. Basically anything. I don't think an example would be useful.

Comment: what kind of app is this? Does it need compilation? Is it JavaScript or PHP or what?

Comment: java spring app. Most of it is configuration files, the actual code is already compiled of course.

Comment: Have you tried defining environment variables in the form of `SOME_PLACE_HOLDER` and see if they get substituted automatically?

Comment: It does not work no. I'm a bit new to docker, I guess it is not possible to modify the content of a file at runtime once the image has already been built?

Comment: @user1278743 yes you can. You can set while building the container.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use a bash file to set all the variables, you can write `set_env_var.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
export PLACEHOLDER1=value
export PLACEHOLDER2=value
```

And run:

```
source set_env_var.sh
```

It will set all the variables.

Or you can run any command by setting multiple variables like this. Eg. I want to run a docker-compose command with variables in it by:

```sh
    PLACEHOLDER1=value PLACEHOLDER2=value docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: This is not the question OP is asking. Please re-read the question

Comment: This does the same thing you are asking. You basically need to set all those variables fixed as environment variables before building your images. This method replaces all the variables you need when run as they would be set as environment variables.

Comment: I don't quite understand how it works, even if I add all those properties in the environment, why would the files inside my already built image be affected?

Comment: How can you change the variables in an image. These can be only changed in a container or before building an image. In both the cases, this works.

Comment: I made changes to my initial post to explain my problem a bit more clearly. It sound very strange that you cannot change that were build in the image.